# Python-Tkinter-askopenfilename: Use filepath of the opened file for reading values

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to store the filepath to an opened file (via askopenfilename in tkinter) into a variable and later on use it for other purposes such as reading the file through the variable and use its values. How do I do that?

Also I am an absolute beginner so please explain the procedure too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] askopenfilename`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+askopenfilename)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to start you off

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


filename = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Attach file", initialdir = 'c:/')


f = open(filename, "r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Comment: I have used askopenfilename in a function which gets called when a button is clicked. So the filepath obtained in the variable of the function cant be used outside the loop of the function and so i cant use open() for it. Can you tell me how to store it for use outside of the loop? Here is the code:  def openafile():
    c=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/home',title='Select a file',filetypes=(('all files','*.txt'),('.txt files','*.py')))
b1=tk.Button(tab1,text='open file',command=openafile)
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)      So I cant use c anywhere else,

Comment: @Newbie You should put the code in your question instead.